# Ошибка запуска python на Windows 7

Tags: python, pyqt5, windows-10, windows-7, pyside2

Написал программу на `python 3.8.10 x32bit` скомпилировал код в `.exe` на `windows 10 x64bit` работает отлично. Но, при запуске на `windows 7 x32bit` вылезает такая ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это решить?

**Исходный код на github:** https://github.com/Win322/Project_SAFTD

P.s из за проблем компиляции matplotlib и pyinstaller использую команду: `pyinstaller --exclude-module matplotlib SL_lke2.1.py`

Comment: ошибка скорее всего возникает изза кирилицы в имени пользователя на изначальном пк

Comment: @ganz то есть в названии моего аккаунта windows 10? Или папки пользователя?

Comment: в папке пользователя куда установлен питон, просто переименовать папку или пользователя не выйден, винда создаст файл desktop.ini в котором будет указано что нужно показывать "новое" название, хотя папка будет называться по старому... самый простой способ создать нового админа изначально с латинским ником

Comment: @ganz папка пользователя названа iru , так что дело не в этом

Comment: это её реальное название либо отображаемое? то есть при правом клике на свойствах везде это название? и первая буква латинская?

Comment: @ganz это ее реальное название. Эта ошибка может вылезать если в названии есть спец символы?

Comment: да, но винда обычно запрещает называть папки с некоректно обрабатываемыми символами. я бы пытался узнать что именно за символ u9781 или какой там...

Comment: @ganz понял попытаюсь поискать ошибку, спасибо за помощь)

Comment: @ganz решил проблему. Одна из папок по пути установки была названа "Скетчи". Исправив название все начало работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключается в том что по пути к скетчу не должно содержатся папок с НЕ-латинскими буквами.